# R 4.0.0 : I am trying to change symbols of legend for a plot in ggplot2, at the moment I have overlapping symbols

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm making a plot in ggplot2 with a line and a segment, the symbols for these appear overlapped. I can make it so that their symbols are either both an arrow or both a line using `show.legend`, but I'd like to make the segment an arrow and the line a line. I tried using `override.aes` to alter it after looking for a solution. changing the shape doesn't appear to do anything. setting the line to 0 makes everything disappear for that symbol.

[image: plot image]

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(NULL, aes(x=0, y=0)) + geom_point(alpha = 0) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-2.5,2.5),ylim = c(-2.5,2.5)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, xend=1, y=0, yend=-2, color ="Vector a"),  arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")), show.legend  = T) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept=1, slope=1/2, color = "Line 1"), show.legend  = T) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-2:2)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-2:2)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "blue"), guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(1,1),
  shape = c(1,1)))) +
  labs(

    title = "plot (a) line",
    x = "X Axis",
    y = "Y Axis"
  )
```

Thank you in advance for any advice you have in fixing my problem :).

EDIT: looking around I found out the symbol for either can be changed through `key_glyph = draw_key_rect` with various other draw_keys_ working. they'll still both display at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(NULL, aes(x=0, y=0)) + geom_point(alpha = 0) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-2.5,2.5),ylim = c(-2.5,2.5)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=0, xend=1, y=0, yend=-2, linetype ="Vector a"),
               colour = "blue",
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm"))) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept=1, slope=1/2, color = "Line 1")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-2:2)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-2:2)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "blue")) +
  labs(title = "plot (a) line",
       x = "X Axis",
       y = "Y Axis",
       linetype = NULL,
       colour = "colour")
```

#### Commentary

You cannot easily use one aesthetic for two different geom levels in ggplot; so you need to fiddle with the build up of your data and call to ggplot to use different aesthetics to create the legend you want. I can't find an explicit statement to this effect. In Hadley Wickham (2015) *ggplot2 Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis* it states:

> “A legend may need to draw symbols from multiple layers. For example,
> if you’ve mapped colour to both points and lines, the keys will show
> both points and lines.”

and

> "ggplot2 tries to use the fewest number of legends to accurately convey
> the aesthetics used in the plot. It does this by combining legends
> where the same variable is mapped to diﬀerent aesthetics."

Which goes some way to explaining the issues you were having with your plot.

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>